# jQuery.each variable scope

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following problem:

```
        var loader = new THREE.JSONLoader( true );
        model = JSON.parse(data);
        var modeldata = loader.parse( jQuery.parseJSON(model['value1']) );
        ...
        var modeldata = loader.parse( jQuery.parseJSON(model['value2']) );
        ...
```

WORKS FINE.

```
        var loader = new THREE.JSONLoader( true );
        model = JSON.parse(data);
        jQueryX.each(parts, function(key, value){
                var modeldata = loader.parse( jQuery.parseJSON(model[value]) );
                ...
        });
```

returns 'model is undefined'

Is there a scope problem? I can not see any...

Expert advices welcome...

Comment: Have you tried this:
var modeldata = loader.parse( jQuery.parseJSON(value) );
Because model[key] = value

Comment: Alexander: thanks for pointing that out. I changed the original code and I totally messed up with it. The lines are totally wrong. I changed them back to the original state which look completely different and is working.

Answer (score 0):

> I am not sure about this. parts contains the list of keys (in
>   parts[value]) that are used in model. In other words, the key of model
>   is the value of parts.

You need to just use `jQuery.parseJSON(model[key])`

```
 jQueryX.each(parts, function(key, value) {
      modelData = loader.parse(jQuery.parseJSON(model[key]));
 });
```

`key` is the key by which you get the value.

Comment: I am not sure about this. parts contains the list of keys (in parts[value]) that are used in model. In other words, the key of model is the value of parts. When I use console.log(model[value]) it returns the right variable but after the 'model is undefined' error.